# Make application launcher search for apps in a particular folder?

Tags: linux, jdk

Everytime I want to run an application with Application Launcher (Alt+F2) in my Ubuntu, I have to make a link to that app and put it in /usr/bin folder, Application Launcher won't search in the folder which I've added to $PATH.

I'm installing jdk 1.7 and it has many tools in it's bin folder and I don't want to manually put a link in /usr/bin for each tool in jdk's bin folder. I want AppLauncher to search for them in jdk1.7's folder.

How can I do that? Thanks :)

Comment: What is the full jdk directory path?
How is set the PATH variable?

Comment: I put jdk here: /usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_02

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_02/bin

Comment: Hey, try to change it: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_02/bin fot it: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/jdk1.7.0_02/bin/
and show us the result of this command:
$ echo $PATH